# why is this c code causing a race condition?

Tags: c, multithreading, pthreads

I'm trying to count the number of prime numbers up to 10 million and I have to do it using multiple threads using Posix threads(so, that each thread computes a subset of 10 million). However, my code is not checking for the condition `IsPrime`. I'm thinking this is due to a race condition. If it is what can I do to ameliorate this issue?

I've tried using a global integer array with k elements but since k is not defined it won't let me declare that at the file scope.

I'm running my code using gcc -pthread:

```
/*
Program that spawns off "k" threads
k is read in at command line each thread will compute
a subset of the problem domain(check if the number is prime)

to compile: gcc -pthread lab5_part2.c -o lab5_part2
*/
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef int bool;
#define FALSE 0
#define TRUE 1

#define N 10000000  // 10 Million

int k; // global variable k willl hold the number of threads
int primeCount = 0; //it will hold the number of primes.

//returns whether num is prime
bool isPrime(long num) {
    long limit = sqrt(num);
    for(long i=2; i<=limit; i++) {
        if(num % i == 0) {
             return FALSE;
        }
     }
     return TRUE;
}

//function to use with threads
void* getPrime(void* input){
    //get the thread id
    long id = (long) input;
    printf("The thread id is: %ld \n", id);

    //how many iterations each thread will have to do
    int numOfIterations = N/k;

  //check the last thread. to make sure is a whole number.
  if(id == k-1){
    numOfIterations = N - (numOfIterations * id);
  }

  long startingPoint = (id * numOfIterations);
  long endPoint = (id + 1) * numOfIterations;
  for(long i = startingPoint; i < endPoint; i +=2){
    if(isPrime(i)){
      primeCount ++;
    }
  }
  //terminate calling thread.
  pthread_exit(NULL);
}

int main(int argc, char** args) {
    //get the num of threads from command line
    k = atoi(args[1]);
    //make sure is working
   printf("Number of threads is: %d\n",k );

   struct timespec start,end;

    //start clock
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&start);

    //create an array of threads to run
    pthread_t* threads = malloc(k * sizeof(pthread_t));
    for(int i = 0; i < k; i++){
      pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL,getPrime,(void*)(long)i);
    }

    //wait for each thread to finish
    int retval;
    for(int i=0; i < k; i++){
      int * result = NULL;
      retval = pthread_join(threads[i],(void**)(&result));
    }

    //get the time time_spent
    clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME,&end);
    double time_spent = (end.tv_sec - start.tv_sec) +
                    (end.tv_nsec - start.tv_nsec)/1000000000.0f;

    printf("Time tasken: %f seconds\n", time_spent);

    printf("%d primes found.\n", primeCount);

}
```

the current output I am getting: (using the 2 threads)

`Number of threads is: 2`

`Time tasken: 0.038641 seconds`

`2 primes found.`

Comment: It causes a race condition because you have literally asked it to. Updating a variable from multiple threads is the very definition of a race condition. What did you expect?

Comment: @n.m which variables? the ones inside the `getPrime` function?

Comment: There is one global variable you update, primeCount.

Comment: Side-note: your isPrime() function checks too many values (though I've seen many worse functions, too).  After checking 2, it should at most check the odd divisors from 3 upwards.  If you test 2 and 3 specially, then you can check divisors of the form 6N±1 (5, 7; 11, 13; 17; 19; …) only.  That does check composite divisors (the first such is 25), but it cuts down the workload (2/3 of the odd numbers only; 1/3 of odd and even numbers).  That said, you do limit your search to √N, which is an important saving too.

Comment: Re, "...global integer array with k elements but since k is not defined..." In this case, it's not reasonable for `k` to be very large. You could declare a fixed array that's big enough for any reasonable `k`, and only use its first `k` elements. But don't forget to check the input, and throw an error if the user enters `k > MAX_K`.

Comment: @SolomonSlow yes that fixed my problem. My code works.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler yes I will check from 3 upwards. In regards to 6N(+-) 1. what does that mean?

Comment: 6N±1 means that you have (inside `isPrime()`) a counter that might be called `n` and you run `int n_max = (limit + 5) / 6; for (int n = 1; n  <= n_max; n++) { if (num % (6 * n - 1) == 0) return FALSE; if (num % (6 * n + 1) == 0) return FALSE; }`.  Or you might use: `for (int n = 6; n < limit; n += 6) { if (num % (n - 1) == 0 || num % (n + 1) == 0) return FALSE; }` or something similar.  The basic idea is that you test only those values which are one less than or one greater than a multiple of 6 (hence 5, 7; 11, 13; 17, 19; … as I noted originally).

Answer (score 2):

The counter `primeCount` is modified by multiple threads, and therefore must be atomic.  To fix this using the standard library (which is now supported by POSIX as well), you should `#include <stdatomic.h>`, declare `primeCount` as an `atomic_int`, and increment it with an `atomic_fetch_add()` or `atomic_fetch_add_explicit()`.

Better yet, if you don’t care about the result until the end, each thread can store its own count in a separate variable, and the main thread can add all the counts together once the threads finish. You will need to create, in the main thread, an atomic counter per thread (so that updates don’t clobber other data in the same cache line), pass each thread a pointer to its output parameter, and then return the partial tally to the main thread through that pointer.

This looks like an exercise that you want to solve yourself, so I won’t write the code for you, but the approach to use would be to declare an array of counters like the array of thread IDs, and pass `&counters[i]` as the `arg` parameter of `pthread_create()` similarly to how you pass `&threads[i]`. Each thread would need its own counter.  At the end of the thread procedure, you would write something like, `atomic_store_explicit( (atomic_int*)arg, localTally, memory_order_relaxed );`.  This should be completely wait-free on all modern architectures.

You might also decide that it’s not worth going to that trouble to avoid a single atomic update per thread, declare `primeCount` as an `atomic_int`, and then `atomic_fetch_add_explicit( &primeCount, localTally, memory_order_relaxed );` once before the thread procedure terminates.

Comment: Better yet, avoid sharing data between threads altogether. Make each thread return its own count, sum them up in the main thread. Atomic operations come with a price tag. Not needed.

Comment: @Davislor would that value be passed as an argument pthread_exit()?

Comment: You could pass the address of the counter to `pthread_exit()`. Note that it cannot be local to the thread procedure or the same for every thread. It could be an element of an array of atomic variables.

Comment: But the address of the counter variable cannot be global right or go inside the thread function? So, where would it go? in the argument list for the thread? `pthread_create(&threads[i],NULL, void*function, &newCounter[0])` something like that?

Comment: You’d typically declare an array of them, one per thread, in the procedure that creates the threads. You could also make the array global, but since you only need it to create threads and collect their results, best practice is to declare it only in the scope where it’s used. Pass each thread the address of a different element.

Comment: @Davislor I appreciate the help I will go to sleep and Implement your tips tomorrow. When I get it working I will mark as the correct answer.

Comment: @SimonGarfe "would that value be passed as an argument pthread_exit" You can cast the integer result to `void*` and pass that to pthread_exit, exactly like you pass the input argument in. Cast it back in `main`. That would probably the easiest way of doing it.

Comment: @n.m. That’s potentially undefined behavior and I don’t recommend it. That said, it’s likely to work on the implementation the OP is using.

Comment: @Davislor, thread-local variables are sometimes useful when you're trying to port old, thread-unaware code that uses global variables into a multi-threaded system. But if you use thread-local variables in _new_ code, then there's probably a better way to solve the problem. Thread-local only makes sense when the variable has global extent. If you want your code to be testable, maintainable, portable, etc.; then you should avoid using globals.